# Maven : Multi Module order

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm creating a Multi-module maven project and module execution order that I want is Parent,Child1Plugin,Child,Child2. Also Child1Plugin has dependency of CHild2.But as of now the reactor is running the following order of modules:

```
**Reactor Summary:**
[INFO] parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT .............................. SUCCESS [  0.387 s]
[INFO] Child2 ............................................. SUCCESS [  2.768 s]
[INFO] Child1Plugin ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.182 s]
[INFO] Child 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ............................... SUCCESS [  0.102 s]

***Parent:***
<groupId>com.io</groupId>
  <artifactId>ParentMod</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>parent</name>
  <description>Thisisparent</description>
  
  <modules>
    <module>Child1Plugin</module>
    <module>Child</module>
    <module>Child2</module>
  </modules>
  
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>

**Child1Plugin**

@Mojo(name = "dependency-counter", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class DependencyCounterMojo extends AbstractMojo{
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
       System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ....Mojo execution begins.... $$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        GenerateFeature ob=new GenerateFeature();
        ob.generationFeature();
    }
  Pom.xml:
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.io</groupId>
        <artifactId>ParentMod</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Child1Plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.io</groupId>
            <artifactId>Child2</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

   **Child2**
 public class GenerateFeature {
 public void generationFeature() {
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ....I am generating feature files");}
  Pom.xml:
     <parent>
        <groupId>com.io</groupId>
        <artifactId>ParentMod</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Child2</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  **Child**
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.io</groupId>
        <artifactId>ParentMod</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </parent>
      <artifactId>Child</artifactId>
      
      <build>
      <plugins>    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.io</groupId>
                <artifactId>Child1Plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>dependency-counter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
      </build>
```

Using above modules I m trying to first install plugin using module-Child1Plugin and then invoke the goal using the module-Child and atlast run my cucumber tests using module-Child2.But reactor is producing a different order due to which I am unable to achieve what i want.

Comment: If `Child1` has a dependency on `Child2`, then `Child2` must be executed before `Child1`. If you want to run the tests after `Child1` and `Child2`, then move them to a separate module and give the new module a dependency on both `Child1` and `Child2`. The actual question is, however: why do tests in `Child2` need `Child1`? That seems wrong.

Comment: I would prefer the order as : 1. Child1Plugin (this installs the plugin) 2. Child (this invokes the goal/mojo as created using plugin in Step 1) 3. Child2 ( this invoke my tests)

Comment: Again: if `Child1` has a dependency on `Child2`, `Child2` must be compiled first. This is a direct consequence of the dependency graph. If the execution must be the other way around, the dependency must be inverted.

Comment: yes child2 is running first than child1 thats what i have posted in reactor summary result but i would wan the result to be in order : 1. Child1Plugin (this installs the plugin) 2. Child (this invokes the goal/mojo as created using plugin in Step 1) 3. Child2 ( this invoke my tests)

Comment: And I just told you: If you want `Child1` to run first, then you have to invert the dependency. If `Child2` depends on `Child1`, `Child1` will be executed first. This, however, requires that the dependency from `Child1` to `Child2` is removed, since maven cannot handle circular dependencies.

Comment: no i cant invert the dependency thats the thing.. and also child module has to be invoked after child1 and before child 2. so is there a way that with my current structure can i make any change to achieve the order i have asked for?

Comment: Not that I know of, no. This would also be challenging for the compiler since the maven-dependency basically states that the compiled result of `Child2` is needed in order to compile `Child1`.

Comment: The only way is to define the dependencies correctly between the modules. The order of the reactor is calculated by Maven. If you are saying you can't change the dependencies it looks your build is broken. 
If you are installing a plugin for later testing in the same reactor that will work only under very limited constraints (and you should really know what you are doing). 
Generally do not try so.

Answer (score 3):

If A has a dependency on B, then B has to be build before A.

This is not just a Maven rule, it is a rule of common sense.

Otherwise, the build of A would break because B would not exist.

So in the stated way, the desired behaviour could not be achieved, not with Maven, or with any build tool that follows basic logic.

Comment: I think I will have to change structure now.. but can you suggest how can I implement following : 1. Module A installs my custom plugin 2. Module B use my custom plugin (invokes mojo) to call a class from a different project (Module C) 3. Module C runs now after A and B to run some JUnit tests. This is the flow I m trying to create using multi module approach.

Comment: If B uses C, but C should run after B, that is not possible. Please step back from your approach, you are going in the wrong direction. I am completely sure that your _real problem_ has a solution, but your ordering problem does not have one. Take a piece of paper, write down what needs to run, and then figure out a set of modules that does this.

Comment: Module A should install a plugin is basically wrong cause a module does not install a plugin. It generates an artifact. This artifact can be a plugin. To be sure that the artifact is built before the one it's using it you have to define a dependency to it. And there is already the problem. Defining a dependency on a plugin make no sense and using a plugin does no influence the build order of the reactor. The question is here: Is Module B a kind of a test? If so your setup is wrong and will not work.

Comment: can i create two separate projects and put a dependency without creating a parent module and execute them... project 1(plugin) and project2(my classes that i need to execute).

Comment: You can have dependencies between independent projects. But still, if A has a dependency on B, you need to build B before you can build A.